# What considerations should guide the number of significant digits used in a Monte Carlo study?

Tags: monte-carlo

Typically random numbers are easy to find or generate. The Monte Carlo (MC) studies I have done in the past used random numbers with many (e.g., 10) digits, just because they were available.  That availability has changed, at least for the contemplated MC study, as I plan to use numbers from a physical source rather than machine generated. (See [How best to form many short, independent random numbers from one long random number?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327453/how-best-to-form-many-short-independent-random-numbers-from-one-long-random-num)).

I am studying the relationship between employment test scores and measures of job performance.  In the real world, such variables are rarely measured to more than 2 significant digits and never measured to more than 3 significant digits.  Meta-analysis results are likewise typically reported to 2 digits ant rarely 3 digits.

In doing MC simulations of such variables, should I be guided by the real world and use 3 digit random numbers? Or should I use more significant digits?  Would it make any difference?  Is one approach to be preferred over the other?  What length random numbers are needed for a Monte Carlo study for such variables or in general?

Comment: What do you mean..? If you generate random numbers on the computer then you can probably choose between 32 and 64 bit floats, but unless you explicitly round them, it has nothing to do with 2 or 3 significant digits....

Comment: I plan to use random numbers from a physical source, not machine generated.

Comment: Then this depends on what you're simulating etc., if you are simulating human height in cm, then two significant digits is even more then you need, if you are simulating something that ranges between 1e-10 and 1e-14, then your simulation would be useless... You need to be more precise.

Comment: @Tim  To restate your comment, the number of significant digits should be guided by the number of such digits in the situation that is being simulated. There is no reason to use numbers with more precision.  That is the answer I was seeking.  (Pardon my naivete.)

Comment: Yes. I'll post it as an answer if this is what you were asking.

Comment: @Tim Yes, please do.